# Lambda is not authorised to perform: cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser on resource:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless

I am trying to create user in aws cognito from a aws lambda function. When I do that I receive an error. Looks like the lambda is not authorised to create the cognito user. Can some share me the serverless.yml file for providing lambda access to cognito. Currently my serverless.yml looks like this

```
functions:
  orderSubmission:
    handler: api/order.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: /orders
          method: post
```

This is what I tried and it dint work

```
functions:
  orderSubmission:
    role: myCustRole0
    handler: api/order.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: /orders
          method: post
          


myCustRole0:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: MyCustRole0
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
               Service:
                 - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: "cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser"
```

Comment: Did you check their docs? https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam

Comment: ya, I went through it.. dint get the direct answer for cognito

Comment: It's basically just an extra permission `cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser` that needs to be added to the role for the `orderSubmission` lambda

Comment: @LRutten I tried doing that.. but dint work.. I have added what I tried to the answer. can you please help?